LD_PRELOAD on Android causing app to hang
I am trying to use LD_PRELOAD to intercept native library calls for an existing android app.
I have downloaded latest NDK and built a simple shared library which currently does nothing other than export a single unused symbol (for testing purposes).
I have followed the steps here (https://cedric.ninja/post/intercepting-android-native-library-calls/) to disable SELinux and set the appropriate wrap property for the app in question to LD_PRELOAD the test library above (have also verified shared object has read/execute permissions on the device).
However, when I try to start the app with the wrap property set, it simply hangs (app window opens but just displays the app's startup screen and never actually initializes properly). If I remove the wrap property, app works fine again. Just to be clear, my LD_PRELOAD'ed lib at this point does nothing other than export an unused random symbol (not trying to intercept any symbols in the app at this stage).
Any ideas why this might be happening or how I might debug what is going on here?
Thanks.

I assume you have root, or else you won't be able to disable selinux. (BTW, an alternative to disabling selinux is to use chcon u:object_r:apk_data_file:s0 on the .so file.) You might also try moving the shared library (and changing LD_PRELOAD to match) to /data/local/tmp/
